# Structure test scripts with liquibase to execute in order with normal scripts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, liquibase

we are using liquibase for migrating database in spring boot application. In resources we have main changelog file which includes other changelogs (1 per version).

We usually differentiate environments by liquibase's context attribute but new we need differentiate data which are only for integration tests, and don't want place it next to normal versioned scripts. Is possible place these integration tests scripts in test's scope of project and execute them in order with normal scripts?

For instance:

main changelog:

```
<include file="version-1.xml"/>
<include file="version-2.xml"/>
```

and version 1 sample:

```
<changeSet id="1ver_1" author="xxx">
     <!-- creation of table foo_table -->
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="1ver_2" author="xxx">
     <!-- adding column to table foo_table -->
</changeSet>
```

version 2 sample:

```
<changeSet id="2ver_1" author="xxx">
     <!-- renaming table foo_table to bar_table -->
</changeSet>
```

I need that if scripts for integration tests will written after script 1ver_1 and will contains inserts, it will be ok if next will be executed 1ver_2 and 2ver_1.

So when db for instegration tests started, scripts will be executed in right order:

1. 1ver_1
2. test_data for 1ver_1
3. 1ver_2
4. 2ver_1

what is best practice to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the way you keep your changesets. Have a look at [Liquibase Best Practices](https://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html). 
So your master changelog should look like:

```
<include file="version-1.1.xml"/>
<include file="version-1.2.xml"/>
<include file="version-2.1xml"/>
```

If you do this, you can have dedicated master changelog file for integration test. Your integration test's changelog-master.xml will look like this:

```
<include file="version-1.1.xml"/>
<include file="test_data_version-1.1.xml"/>
<include file="version-1.2.xml"/>
<include file="version-2.1xml"/>
```

After that you just override property in integration tests:

```
liquibase.change-log=classpath:integration-liquibase-changeLog.xml
```

Also you should place `integration-liquibase-changeLog.xml` and all 'test_data_xx.xml' into integration test module resource or test resource (it depends on project structure). The main idea it should not be provided to production artifacts.

Comment: I think we are using this concept. From docs: `The most common way to organize your changelogs is by major release.` Where `Version X` is our release, and each release contains multiple change sets. But when someone write change set 1 for version 1, and also data for current db state, and someone else change db structure in change set 2 of version 1, how to handle this case? It needs run test data between changesets which are in same file of version 1.

Comment: Have a look at updated answer. You can find example how your master changeset should look like if you follow the Best Practices. If so you are able to create integration tests chanelog. In your integration tests you have to check that changes from  `version-1.2.xml` does not corrupt or even truncate your data from prev (`version-1.1.xml`) release. You do not need insert data for the intergation tests between changeSets because it is  not a real case. You will not get this situation in your production. Because liquibase apply all changesets from `version-1.1xml`, but not part of it.

Comment: But there is possible that db structure will changed between changesets. For instance you can imagine 2 devs are working on release 1.5. First create some structure, and want add some data for hist integration tests. Second will change 1.5 changelog, and adds some changeset which modify structure of first dev. In this case is required execute scripts with test data betweens changes of these 2 devs, to apply changes of second dev on inserted data of first dev.

Comment: Both of them have to add data before 1.5 right after 1.4 but not in the middle of 1.5. Because your integration tests should check how developer's changes affect data that were added on 1.4. (the data that exists in the system before 1.5 migration).

Comment: You should emulate real cases and states of your system in your integration tests. No data added by the system during migration 1.5. Therefore both developers should add test data to separate file that applied before 1.5 and after 1.4 (sample you can find in my answer).

Comment: No data will added between changesets. As I said, 2 devs working on release 1.5 which represents 1 changelog file with multiple changesets. First developer add changesets where create table, for example with 4 columns. He also write some integration tests so he needs create also inserts for that 4 columns. Next second developer need split that table in different task into 2 tables with 2 cols, and write migration scripts which split table with data, which write previous developer. In this case data scripts need be executed between changesets of release 1.5.

Comment: Nice example! But when you deploy release 1.5 which represents 1 changelog file, you apply this changes to data that stored in structure 1.4. So both of developers should test it on 1.4 and add it to separate file `test-data-before-1.5.xml` that can be executed before 1.5. There is no reason insert data in the middle of 1.5 changes. Is`t it?

Comment: Just look at deployment procedure you apply both developers changes to the data with 1.4 structure. So we must do the same on integration test. Therefore all data for integration tests, that check 1.5 metadata changes, have to be added before 1.5 file execution

Comment: Your integration test should look like this: 1. Add data to DB version 1.4 (both devs add it to the same file) 2) Apply devs changes 1.5. It migrates the DB to 1.5 version  3) Run integration test which validate that result data are present and consistent.

Comment: These data are not executed only during deploy, but also between releases when developer creating new features ( example with changing table structure as I said) and want execute tests if all is still fine and in this moment if inserts willl written for changeset 1, but changeset 2 change structure of previous table, and test data will executed after whole release's scripts it will crash.

Comment: Sorry, I get wrong your example. It is quite unusual situation :). Why second developer have to write new migration scripts which split table. He have to just  replace first developer's table with new two tables. What is the point in creation of a wrong structured table and immediately alter that change it. It make sense only when you need this changes between releases. Isn't it?

Comment: it was just example and some corner case which I need cover with solution.

Comment: :) Sorry, by my opinion, creation of new changesets, is wrong way to fix this issue. Second developer can and have to change table structure without new changeset if he works in the same release where this table was created.

Comment: No probs, it was interesting corner case. (but I think it should be fixed by the dev process changes)